# Laravel - How to use a foreign key to a table with an identifying foreign key?

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys

So I have three tables: `users`, `candidates` and `logs`. Now `candidates` does not have its own id, it has an identifying foreign key `user_id`. Looking much like this:

```
-users-
id
name
etc.

-candidates-
user_id
type
etc.
```

Now I want to have a table `logs` that has a one-to-many relation with `candidates`, being that a candidate can have zero or more `logs`. So I want to have a foreign key to `candidates`, something like `candidate_id`. However, putting it like this and Laravel won't automagically understand the relation. What should I name the foreign key from `logs` to `candidates` to make Laravel understand the relationship?

Comment: Is the users->candidates relationship a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Yes @tkausl, it indeed is. A user does not necessarily have a candidate though, but a candidate does necessarily have a user.

Comment: Then you could let the user have the logs as relationship, the candidates could then have a log through the user (`hasManyThrough`). There is no way to have a one-to-many relationship without a primary-key on the "one" part.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing would be to give candidates its own incremental id and then have two relationship tables, candidate_user and candidate_log. It would be set up according to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: The sql-structure I describe in my question is not illogical or unorthodox to sql is it? Because I think Laravel should support all valid sql-structures and thus my question should be answerable without a workaround. Agree?

Answer (score 0):

Your candidates table must have a primary key.

There's no need to have an incremental ID, but you shouldn't leave the table without a primary key.

Once you define a primary key, you can use it as your reference.

Laravel will try to guess your foreign_key name:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the Comment model is post_id.

If your primary key is not the "id" column, you should use the `protected $primaryKey` and the `public $incrementing` properties to describe your primary key in your Eloquent Model.